# Unable to find [App Inspection] option in Android Studio under View <Tool Window<

Tags: android-studio-3.0, app-inspection

I want to do network inspection on my android app running in emulator of android studio and want to inspect all respond and request content. I get to know that same can be done by clicking on App Inspection and App inspection is there in View<Tool Windows < App Inspection.  But this option is not available there.
Is there any problem with my configuration. Also it seems like my emulator device is offline. However my app is working fine in the emulator device.

I have tried creating various AVDs as I believe it is something to do with AVD config.

Comment: Hi, I got the same problem here. Any update regarding this issue?